# I want to install executable of amd64 (x86) architecture on ARM architecture

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, arm, x86

I have just installed software (LabView linux supported version) on my laptop and its working fine. 
Recently I installed it on ARM cortex-A9 processor (zynq 7z020) and successfully installed all packages. Problem is; when I run the executable, It shows following error : 
**"Cannot execute binary file"**

This error is due to mismatch of architecture, because version of LabView supported for x86 architecture and I am installing it on ARM.
I have recently try to install wine to run executables but wine not running on ARM.

**Kindly guide me how to install the executable on ARM?**
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Use [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You generally cannot run binaries using a different CPU architecture under Linux.   Efforts have been made on making this happen, but has not gained traction.

It appears from https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/downloads/software-products/download.labview.html#305508 that LabView is not available for your platform (they only consider the x64 platform which is Intel/AMD, not ARM).

Emulation will not make you happy.

Consider writing them and ask for it, and then find a PC to run LabView on in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

if you can find a x86 (32bit) version of the program, you can try to run it with [box86](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box86).